# useState React not updating

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm having trouble with react useState hook.
I have called backend-api and I want to set result to userData.

api called successfully, I can see console.log(response.data).
{“message":"ok","data":[{"id":1,"name":"hyu","birth":"2000.1.1","gender":0,"remarks":"test"}]}

here is the code.

```
import React , {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
const [userData, setUserData] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('api/babyinfo');
        console.log(response.data);
        setUserData(response.data);
      }
      getUser();
    },[]);
    console.log(userData); //  userData is still empty
```

Dose anyone know what is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: There is no issue in the code. Its just that you are trying to print the value before the state is updated.

Comment: If you use user data in the render, the view will update with that data after the data is retrieved from the backend

Comment: how can I  use Userdata after updating? I am trying to display these response on ui, but nothing show..  <p>{userData.name}</p>

Comment: !_.isEmpty(userData) ? userData : [] try something like this. I think your page rend before data load (_.isEmplty is lodash lib method you can try with if condition )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import React , {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
    
            const getUser = async () => {
               try {
               const response = await axios.get('api/babyinfo');
               console.log(response.data);
               setUserData(response.data.data);
               }catch(err) => {
              console.log(err)
              }
              }
                 
                 useEffect(() => {
                 getUser();
                },[])
```

Now, You can console your state to see if your state is updated

```
console.log(userData);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue in the code, and its just that you are trying to access an array as an object.

Please try this

```
import React , {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('api/babyinfo');
        setUserData(response.data.data[0]);
      }
      getUser();
    },[]);

   return <span>{userData.name}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set type `[ ]` initially in userData like

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]); // here
```

Comment: thank you! I tried useState([]) but still not working :(

Answer (score 1):

const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

setUserData(response.data.data);